# How to write query with multiple conditions?

Tags: sqlite

I have table with column fields date,points and categoryType.

How to write sqlite query to get records from table in between given date
where points value are greater then Zero ( > 0).

```
 Select * from tableName
 where  (Select points FROM tableName
        WHERE date(DateValue) BETWEEN date('2016-12-26') AND date('2016-12-27')
        > 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery would make sense only if it were  correlated.

Just use a simple query, and combine multiple conditions with AND:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE date(DateValue) BETWEEN '2016-12-26' AND '2016-12-27'
  AND points > 0;
```

Comment: My knowledge is week at sqlite query thanks for your input.